# How to put data line by line into a vector

Tags: c++

I want to read a text file line by line (I do not have many integers in each line). I want to sort each line and put them into a vector of a vector. The problem is I cannot insert them into vector line by line. I cannot let them stop at the end of the line. This is what I have now. Can anyone help me?

For example, my text file like this:

```
1 5 3 7 29 17
2 6 9 3 10 
3 89 54 67 34
```

I want my output like this:

```
1: 1 3 5 7 17 29
2: 2 3 6 9 10
3: 3 34 54 67 89
```

```
vector<int> v;
vector<vector<int>> G_AL;

if(line!=0){ // Build matrics
    string lines;
    while (getline(fin, lines)) {
        istringstream os(lines);
        float temp;
        while(os >> temp ) {
            if(temp != '\n') {
                v.push_back(temp);
                sort(v.begin(), v.end());
                // get v
            }
            else
            {

            }
            G_AL.push_back(v);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code there, not using image

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Besides that you must post code as (properly formatted) text, you are required to post a [mcve], what is the purpose if the `if(line != 0)` statement for instance. We cannot see how line was defined and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
std::stringstream fin("2 1 3\n4 6 5\n10 9 7 8"); // Test data
std::vector<std::vector<int>> G_AL;
std::string lines;

while (getline(fin, lines)) {
    std::istringstream os(lines);
    std::vector<int> v;
    float temp;

    while(os >> temp)
        v.push_back(temp);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    G_AL.push_back(v);
}

for (size_t i=0; i<G_AL.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << i+1 << ": ";
    for (auto const & v : G_AL[i])
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

There are some problems in the code you provided:

- The `v` vector is declared outside of the loop, so the values keeps accumulating every line since `v` is not cleared. Declaring it inside the loop fixes the problem and avoid having to clear it.
- The sort can be done only once we finished reading the line.
- You push the `v` vector into `G_AL` after ever value instead of after every line.
- You compare a `float` with a character (\n), which doesn't work. In fact, the line `os >> temp` will evaluate to false if there is no floating point value to read, so there is no need to test once more for the end of the stream.